# Cucumber Java, Gherkin espresso not working

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am writing espresso tests but using feature file scenarios by using Cucumber for Java/Gherkin plug-in.

The feature file pointing at the right steps. But on executing the scenarios from feature file, it throws an exception;
Skipped step

Skipped step

Skipped step

**Exception thrown**

```
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
    at androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:45)
    at androidx.test.rule.ActivityTestRule.<init>(ActivityTestRule.java:166)
    at com.goldengekko.o2pm.cucumber.steps.OfferDetailsQRCodeSteps.<init>(OfferDetailsQRCodeSteps.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
    at enter code hereorg.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
```

**Gradle dependencies**

```
//Cucumber dependencies
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-android:1.2.5'
androidTestImplementation 'info.cukes:cucumber-picocontainer:1.2.5'

androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.3.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.3.0'
```

**CucumberInstrumentationRunner**

```
public class CucumberInstrumentationRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    private final CucumberInstrumentationCore instrumentationCore = new CucumberInstrumentationCore(this);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle bundle) {
        instrumentationCore.create(bundle);
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        waitForIdleSync();
        instrumentationCore.start();
    }
}
```

**CucumberOptions**

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "features", glue = "package.cucumber.steps")
public class CucumberTestCase {
}
```

**Step definitions class**

```
public class OfferDetailsQRCodeSteps {

    ActivityTestRule<SettingsActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(SettingsActivity.class, false, false);
    @Before
    public void launchActivity() throws Exception {
        rule.launchActivity(null);
    }

    @Given("^the user is logged in$")
    public void the_user_is_logged_in() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        onView(ViewMatchers.withId(R.id.logout_button)).perform(click());
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @When("^the user clicks a universal link to a redeemed offer with QR code$")
    public void the_user_clicks_a_universal_link_to_a_redeemed_offer_with_QR_code() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

    @Then("^the QR code modal is displayed$")
    public void the_QR_code_modal_is_displayed() throws Throwable {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        throw new PendingException();
    }

}
```

// path to CucumberInstrumentationRunner class
testInstrumentationRunner "packagename.runner.CucumberInstrumentationRunner"

// androidTest directory structure

androidTest 
   -cucumber 
-runner 
CucumberInstrumentationRunner 
-steps 
OfferDetailsQRCodeSteps 
-test 
CucumberTestCase

assets folder in root of the package 
assets 
-features 
OfferDetailQRCode.feature

Has someone written espresso tests using cucumber and cucumber instrumentation on Androidx implementation ?

Can you please point out where am i going wrong ? Help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Hi yasir, it's nice that you've put in all the necessary details. You might want to look at the formatting of your question though, and edit to make sure it is properly indented so that the code block includes all of the class, or putting the stack trace in a code block also.

Comment: Code formatting applied. Any clue about the actual issue i am facing ? JM Lord.

Comment: I'm not familiar with cucumber, but with other similar testing tools we usually have an annotation on top of the test class, to specify which test runner to use. For example: 
`@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)` or `@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)`. Are you referencing `CucumberInstrumentationRunner`above your test classes?

Comment: Cucumber needs its own instrumentation class. Yes you are right, its CucumberInstrumentationRunner which extends AndroidJUnitRunner class. Thats why I have defined testInstrumentationRunner "package.cucumber.runner.CucumberInstrumentationRunner" in gradle.

Comment: This seems correctly defined, but if I look at the samples here https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/ I see the `@RunWith(Cucumber.class)` annotation I was referring to, but not in your code above.